# Permission Set is not completely retrieved by Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, permission-sets

I'm having this peculiar problem now in which I try to 'refresh from server' on my Eclipse copy of a Sandbox Environment in order to retrieve a Permission Set and all I get is a Permission Set that has so many things missing inside it.

The 'refresh from server' seems it doesn't work because the contents of the Permission Set only has the `<UserPermissions>`, it doesn't have all `<classAccess>`, `<fieldPermissions>`, etc...

Is this an Eclipse bug? I was able to retrieve the Permission Sets on this Sandbox a month ago without any problems but now I can't get correct contents for my Permission Sets.

Lastly, I checked the Package.xml and the value inside is only this:

```
<types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>PermissionSet</name>
</types>
```

I tried adding the specific PermissionSet on the Package.xml and I still can't retrieve correct Permission Sets.

Thanks.

Comment: What all is in your project in Eclipse? It's only going to contain permissions for items in your project.